# Entity Framework 4.1 : Is there a way to switch schema on runtime

Tags: .net, entity-framework, mapping, schema, runtime

up to now (EFv1) we used this solution: http://efmodeladapter.codeplex.com/
after upgrading to .NET Framework 4.0 we are looking for built in way to change schema on runtime when using Entity Framework 4.0/4.1?

to be more specific we have two big schemas on DB (A and B) and only schema A added to the Model. the tables in A and B are identically same.
i am looking for a solution to switch between A and B in runtime.

Answer (score 1):

No. The schema is part of [mapping file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387152.aspx). So the options are either:

- Don't use mapping files as resources. Change the SSDL file at runtime.
- Use two different SSDL files and build connection string at runtime.

Comment: Or MSFT could build this feature in if they actually supported Model First anymore...

Answer (score 1):

I can suggest you two models separately. And depending on the conditions use one or another.
For example

```
void Foo(DbContext model) {
    if (model.GetType() == typeof(FooNamespace.MyFooModel)){
        var db = model as FooNamespace.MyFooModel;
        //Do stuff
    } else {
        var db = model as BarNamespace.MyBarModel;
        //Do stuff
    }
}
```

If your models have some similarities than you can use some interface. If your models share some commone attributes, i.e. both of them have `Category` objects, then having two different namespaces for models solves the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As Ladislav says, You could use two SSDL Files,

Here's how to do it.

- Right click on your .edmx file and choose properties
- change "Metadata artifact Processing" to **Copy to Output Directory**
- open .ssdl file from your output  directory
- replace all **Schema="dbo"** to **Schema="A"**
- Save file as a.ssdl
- Initialize your DbContext using following connection string

  metadata=~/bin/Model1.csdl|~/bin/a.ssdl|~/bin/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string='data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;initial catalog=;integrated security=True;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework';";

Answer (score 0):

This is my take on a similar scenario (very similar to @Greatran answer, but I could not find any *Metadata artifact processing* property item on my .EDMX file):

1. Build at least once your project containing the EDMX file
2. Grab a copy of generated .SSDL file, contained in a subpath of

   ```
   Your\Project\Folder\obj\Debug\edmxResourcesToEmbed\Your\EDMX\Namespace\
   ```
3. Copy and include that under your project, e.g. in the same directory as EDMX file: `...\Your\EDMX\Namespace\MyModel.ssdl`
4. Rename it adding a suffix to match your deploy environment, so e.g. for `Debug` environment it would be `MyModel.Debug.ssdl`
5. From its file properties, set *Build Action* to `Embedded Resource`
6. Grab a copy of related context connection string from the web project `Web.config` file. That should be something like

```
connectionString="metadata=res://\*/XXXXX.MyModel.csdl|
res://*/XXXXX.MyModel.ssdl|
res://*/XXXXX.MyModel.msl; 
provider=ZZZZZ;provider connection string='AAAAA'"
```

1. Transform that connection string in the web project config file for your deploy environment, say `Web.Debug.config`, in order to substitute the EDMX-generated SSDL file with your custom SSDL file:

```
connectionString="metadata=res://\*/XXXXX.MyModel.csdl|
res://*/YYYYY.MyModel.Debug.ssdl|
res://*/XXXXX.MyModel.msl;
provider=ZZZZZ;provider connection string='BBBBB'"
```

The last point could get tricky, at least in my experience, as the namespace of EDMX-generated SSDL resource was different from the namespace of my custom SSDL resource. In order to get the exact namespace for my custom resource, I ran a debug session in VS and checked the output of `this.GetType().Assembly.GetManifestResourceNames()` in Immediate Window (thanks to [stu432](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6856088/embed-custom-ssdl-in-ef-dll)).

Also, I changed the `connection string ='AAAAA'` part in order to match the DB server in deploy environment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution in [c# Entity Framework EF 4.1 Change Schema and Database name at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19982653/696355) works well. It basically changes the schema in the SSDL resource at runtime, so there is no need to generate a new SSDL for each schema used.